# How Mysql's Adaptive-Hash Index works

Tags: mysql, indexing

Assume there has a hash index on column `name`, the hash table should looks like **`prefix of the index key` -> `pages of the index`**, according to this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-adaptive-hash.html

> Based on the observed pattern of searches, a hash index is built using a prefix of the index key. The prefix can be any length, and it may be that only some values in the B-tree appear in the hash index. Hash indexes are built on demand for the pages of the index that are accessed often.

but i want to know why the hash table is not like **`prefix of the index key` -> `result rows`**?

Comment: The hashtable in fact maps a prefix of the index column to logical rows.  I don't understand your question exactly.  Can you clarify what your doubts are?

Comment: The "adaptive hash" is an internal optimization.  You can ignore it.  InnoDB has no "Hash" indexing, only BTree, Fulltext, and Spatial.  Stackoverflow focuses on _usage_ of the product, not the _internals_.

Comment: You can ask this question at dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen i'm just doubt what the hashtable really be? "Hash indexes are built on demand for the pages of the index that are accessed often." from official document make me puzzled, Are there has anything to do with "pages of the index"?

Comment: You should start by reviewing a good tutorial on how indices work in databases.